# Improving this script - GPX reading and processing with Python OGR

Tags: python, ogr, gpx

I am trying to plot every GPX trace I have in a folder, by reading it with Python-OGR, clipping it by a bounding box, and plotting

Curently I have a working script, but it seems very uggly, and I suspect there should be a more straightforward way to achieve the same results.

Specific questions in comments:

```
#coding:utf-8

import glob
import ogr
import json
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# 1) Is there a more direct or idiomatic way to create this rectangle?
ring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
ring.AddPoint(-51.22, -30.027)
ring.AddPoint(-51.22, -30.047)
ring.AddPoint(-51.18, -30.047)
ring.AddPoint(-51.18, -30.027)
ring.AddPoint(-51.22, -30.027)

poly = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
poly.AddGeometry(ring)



for filename in sorted(glob.glob('../../../04 GPS/REGISTROS/*/*.gpx'), reverse=True)[:1]:

    # 2) Are all those "if not X: continue" statements the right way to check?
    datasource = ogr.Open(filename)
    if not datasource:
        continue

    layer = datasource.GetLayerByName('tracks')
    if not layer:
        continue

    feature = layer.GetNextFeature()  # Shouldn't I get *every* feature?
    if not feature:
        continue

    geometry = feature.GetGeometryRef().Intersection(poly)
    if not geometry:
        continue


    # 3) Exporting was the only way I found
    # to get numeric values. Is there any other?
    j = json.loads(geometry.ExportToJson())


    # 4) one of returned objects have only "geometry" key...
    if not 'coordinates' in j:
        continue

    for segment in j['coordinates']:
        seg = numpy.array(segment, ndmin=2)
        plt.plot(seg[:,0], seg[:,1], lw=0.5, alpha=0.1)


plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have many solutions but you choose to use ogr and the GeoJSON format (you could have chosen [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) and [shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) or one of the many modules to parse gpx files: [Pypi:gpx](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=gpx&submit=search) or to parse XML files).

#### 1) Is there a more direct or idiomatic way to create this rectangle?

ogr is is verbose, look at [Python GDAL/OGR Cookbook](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html)

With the GeoJSON format:

```
import json
polygs = {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-51.22, -30.027, 0.0], [-51.22, -30.047, 0.0], [-51.18, -30.047, 0.0], [-51.18, -30.027, 0.0], [-51.22, -30.027, 0.0]]]}
poly = ogr.CreateGeometryFromJson(json.dumps(polygs))
```

With shapely and the wkt format:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
polys = Polygon([(-51.22,-30.027, 0),(-51.22, -30.047, 0),(-51.18, -30.047, 0),(-51.18, -30.027, 0),(-51.22, -30.027, 0)])
poly = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(polys.wkt)
```

#### 2) Are all those "if not X: continue" statements the right way to check?

Use a single for loop to find the layers in a gpx file (replace your script for loops)

```
from osgeo import ogr
datasource = ogr.Open('my.gpx')
for i in range(datasource.GetLayerCount()):
     print datasource.GetLayer(i).GetName()," :", datasource.GetLayer(i).GetFeatureCount()     
 waypoints  : 0
 routes  : 0
 tracks  : 1
 route_points  : 0
 track_points  : 547
```

#### 3) Exporting was the only way I found to get numeric values. Is there any other?

Examine the first layer with one feature: `tracks`:  what is the geometry ?

```
 # geometry type
 layer = datasource.GetLayerByName('tracks')
 first = layer.GetFeature(0)
 geom = first.GetGeometryRef()
 print geom.GetGeometryName()
 MULTILINESTRING
```

a) Processing with the GeoJSON format: define two simple functions to plot the lines and the multilines formats from GeoJSON coordinates with matplotlib (you don't need the segments computation)

```
 def plot_line(ax, ob, col):
      x,y = zip(*[(j[0],j[1]) for j in ob])
      ax.plot(x, y, color=col)

 def plot_multiline(ax, ob,col):
      for line in ob:
         plot_line(ax,line,col)
```

Plot the feature

```
 # transform the geometry to GeoJSON format
 import json
 geomjson = json.loads(geom.ExportToJson())
 # plot the feature
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 fig = plt.figure() 
 ax = fig.gca() 
 geomcoor = geomjson['coordinates']
 if geomjson['type'] == 'LineString':
     plot_line(ax, a,'g')
 if  geomjson['type'] == 'MultiLineString':
     plot_multiline(ax, a,'g')
```

Result:
[image]

If there are many features, use a simple for loop

b) Examine the second layer with features: `tracks_points` (Points) and simple processing **without** the GeoJSON format

```
layer2 = datasource.GetLayerByName('track_points')
fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.gca() 
for i in range(layer2.GetFeatureCount()):
     point = layer2.GetFeature(i)
     geom_point = point.GetGeometryRef()
     x,y,z = geom_point.GetPoint()
     ax.scatter(x,y)
```

Result:

[image]

It is easy to adapt these solutions with:

```
geometryfeature.GetGeometryRef().Intersection(poly)
```

### New: solution with Fiona and shapely

```
import fiona
fiona.listlayers('my.gpx')
[u'waypoints', u'routes', u'tracks', u'route_points', u'track_points']
# open layer tracks
layer = fiona.open('my.gpx', layer='tracks')
geom = layer[0] # only one feature here)
geom['geometry']['type']
'MultiLineString'
# convert to shapely geometry
from shapely.geometry import shape, mapping
tracks = shape(geom['geometry'])
```

Polygon

```
polygs = {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(-79.159610379971326, 35.615399458474776), (-79.153546268732796, 35.615411586697256), (-79.153109652723629, 35.611215221720187), (-79.159392071966749, 35.611118195940371), (-79.159610379971326, 35.615399458474776)]]}
poly = shape(polygs)
```

Intersection:

```
geometry = poly.intersection(tracks)
mapping(geometry)['type']
'MultiLineString'
```

Plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from descartes.patch import PolygonPatch
def plot_poly(ax,ob):
   patch = PolygonPatch(ob, facecolor='#6699cc', edgecolor='#6699cc')
   ax.add_patch(patch)
def plot_line(ax, ob, col):
   x, y = ob.xy
   ax.plot(x, y, color=col)
def plot_multiline(ax, ob,col):
   for line in ob:
      plot_line(ax,line,col)

fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.gca()
plot_multiline(ax, tracks,'b')
plot_poly(ax,poly)
plot_multiline(ax, geometry,'r')
```

Result:

[image]

And you can save the resulting shapefile:

```
schema = {'geometry': 'MultiLineString','properties': {'test': 'int'}}
with fiona.open('intersect.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema) as output:
     feature = {'geometry': {'coordinates': mapping(geometry)['coordinates'] ,'type': 'MultiLineString'},'properties': {'test': 1}}
     output.write(feature)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice answer! Perhaps I have not expressed myself right, but I have NO special interest in GeoJson format. Actually, I am fond of Numpy, and usually I convert things to numpy arrays. Also, I use OGR because I could not use Fiona to read GPX files (perhaps I did something wrong). Your suggestion of using Fiona + Shapely is very interesting to me, would you mind posting some example code?

Comment: look above for a solution with Fiona-shapely

Comment: Thank you a lot. I haven't tested the answer yet, but I learned many new ways of doing things here, and it helped me very much.

Answer (score 1):

here's a slightly modified version of your code. my changes are in the main loop and I made it such that you iterate over all features. I did not execute it so I apologize if there are any syntax errors!

```
#coding:utf-8

import glob
import ogr
import json
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# 1) Is there a more direct or idiomatic way to create this rectangle?
ring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
ring.AddPoint(-51.22, -30.027)
ring.AddPoint(-51.22, -30.047)
ring.AddPoint(-51.18, -30.047)
ring.AddPoint(-51.18, -30.027)
ring.AddPoint(-51.22, -30.027)

poly = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
poly.AddGeometry(ring)

for filename in sorted(glob.glob('../../../04 GPS/REGISTROS/*/*.gpx'), reverse=True)[:1]:

    # 2) Are all those "if not X: continue" statements the right way to check?
    datasource = ogr.Open(filename)
    if not datasource:
        continue

    layer = datasource.GetLayerByName('tracks')
    if not layer:
        continue

    feature = layer.GetNextFeature()  # Shouldn't I get *every* feature?
    while feature is not None:
        geometry = feature.GetGeometryRef().Intersection(poly)
        if geometry is not None:  #haven't run this...I assume None is returned if there's no intersection
            seg = []
            for i in range(0, geometry.GetPointCount()):
                seg.append(geom.GetPoint(i))

            seg = np.array(seg)
            plt.plot(seg[:,0], seg[:,1], lw=0.5, alpha=0.1)

        feature = layer.GetNextFeature()

plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```